# Can Amazon Lex be used with other platforms (eg. Google Home)?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, conversational-ui

I'm trying to figure out which open source framework to use to start building a conversational AI for our business. We are a financial technology company so security/ privacy is just as important as ability to build features quickly.

Amazon Lex seems to be a good choice, is it possible to use it with Google Home or other voice assistants?

Also, any additional advice on which platform to use/ architecture would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes Amazon Lex can work with other services. From the Lex website:

"With Amazon Lex, you can build, test, and deploy your chatbots directly from the Amazon Lex console. Amazon Lex enables you to easily publish your voice or text chatbots to mobile devices, web apps, and chat services such as Facebook Messenger, Slack, Kik, and Twilio SMS. Once published, your Amazon Lex bot processes voice or text input in conversation with your end-users. Amazon Lex is a fully managed service so as your user engagement increases, you don’t need to worry about provisioning hardware and managing infrastructure to power your bot experience."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit more complex than that! Adding a bit more here as this is coming up in Google searches:

Yes, it can integrate with Facebook Messenger, Slack, Kik and Twilio SMS — those have options direct in the Lex interface for linking those services. When it comes to Google Home, you'd need to create your own bridge between Amazon Lex and [Google's Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/).

So you'd take what the Google Actions SDK hears someone say when they speak to their Google Home (the fulfilment text), and then need to pass that onto Amazon Lex. To do that, you need to use Amazon Lex's `postText` or `postContent` functions ([Lex Runtime docs on that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html)). I haven't done this myself just yet, but I've heard of others doing similar and spotted this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556376/can-i-use-amazon-lex-with-google-assistant) explaining it in a bit more detail when looking for an example.