# Can I use Amazon LEX with Google assistant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, google-voice, assistant

I have made a Chat-Bot using Amazon's [LEX](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/what-is.html).

Is there any way I can use that application using Google's [Voice Assistant](https://assistant.google.com/intl/en_in/) in my phone?

If not why?

Comment: direct integration is not possible right now you have few options here you can use google voice to text library to convert voice into text and then send it to lex and get response back or you can use dialog flow by google if you need further help i'm open for discussion

Comment: @varnit can you please provide me some links on how to do that?

Comment: which approach you would prefer out of two ?

Comment: @varnit the first option that you've suggested

Comment: for that you need to create a custom app are you ok with that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this term "custom app". But please explain.

Comment: custom app means you have to create your own app in android and use lex and google speech to text libraries

Comment: it would be easy and better if you use DialogFlow instead of Amazon Lex, any particular reason you do not want to use DialogFlow?

Comment: @sid8491 I know about DialogFlow but my whole App-ecosystem is on AWS, I do not wan't to switch to GCP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use Google's voice assistant application with Amazon Lex as NLP engine.

- Go to https://developers.google.com/actions/ and log in
- Go to Actions Console using button on top left corner
- Create an Amaaon Lex agent
- In your actions's SDK use [Lex's runtime library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html) to `postContent` or `postText` function to call Lex and get intent name
- Make your functions in Actions SDK to return fulfillment text

Pseudo Code in Nodejs :

```
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const rp = require('request-promise');


const app = actionssdk({debug: true});

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
  conv.ask('Hi!');
});

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
  // here you will write code to call amazon lex and pass input text
  intent_name = lex_library(input) 

  return rp({
    intent_name
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // create an intent-action mapper
    const actionMap = {
      name: nameIntent,
      help: helpIntent,
    };
    // check the intent name from Lex
    if (res.intent_name && res.intent_name !== 'None') {

      // Map intents to functions for different responses
      actionMap[res['intent_name']](conv);

    } else {      
      conv.ask('Sorry, I don\'t understand what you mean.');
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error =>', e);
  });
});

function nameIntent(conv) {
  conv.ask('My name is noobie. Hope you are fine!');
} 

function helpIntent(conv) {
  conv.ask('Help response');
}

express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(8888)
```

Please note that you will need to have understanding of action's sdk and lex runtime library to extend above code according to your need.
This is high level approach to achieve your goal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @noobie its amazon lex's run-time library, you need to use either postText or postContent functions from it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html